# Magnifier is not showing

Tags: magento2, xml, gallery

Magnifier is not showing. Option enable set to true.

Settings in my theme:
Vendor/MyTheme/etc/view.xml

```
<var name="magnifier">
    <var name="fullscreenzoom">10</var>  <!-- Zoom for fullscreen (integer)-->
    <var name="top"></var> <!-- Top position of magnifier -->
    <var name="left"></var> <!-- Left position of magnifier -->
    <var name="width">300</var> <!-- Width of magnifier block -->
    <var name="height">300</var> <!-- Height of magnifier block -->
    <var name="eventType">hover</var> <!-- Action that atcivates zoom (hover/click) -->
    <var name="enabled">true</var> <!-- Turn on/off magnifier (true/false) -->
    <var name="mode">outside</var> <!-- Zoom type (outside/inside) -->
</var>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was looking in a lot of questions. Solution was simple, just play with settings,specially with numbers.

My theme is extending blank theme, current settings (its also work well with inside mode):

```
<var name="magnifier">
    <var name="fullscreenzoom">10</var>  <!-- Zoom for fullscreen (integer)-->
    <var name="top"></var> <!-- Top position of magnifier -->
    <var name="left"></var> <!-- Left position of magnifier -->
    <var name="width">20</var> <!-- Width of magnifier block -->
    <var name="height">20</var> <!-- Height of magnifier block -->
    <var name="eventType">hover</var> <!-- Action that atcivates zoom (hover/click) -->
    <var name="enabled">true</var> <!-- Turn on/off magnifier (true/false) -->
    <var name="mode">outside</var> <!-- Zoom type (outside/inside) -->
</var>
```

Zoom option is not working for me so I added some css:

```
.magnifier-preview:not(.hidden) {
    zoom: 2;
}
```

**I found that to better not use CSS, but add better resolution Image to product to take this effect.**